# EditText force submit button to be on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have a form for the user to fill out and the last item of the form is an EditText that supports multiple lines.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ContactUs.ContactUs">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/baseline_margin_unit"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_margin_unit"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_margin_unit">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contact_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/contact_us_name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:floatingLabel="normal"
            app:floatingLabelText="@string/contact_us_name" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/contact_us_phone_number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:floatingLabel="normal"
            app:floatingLabelText="@string/contact_us_phone_number" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/contact_us_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:floatingLabel="normal"
            app:floatingLabelText="@string/contact_us_email" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/contact_us_message"
            app:floatingLabel="normal"
            app:floatingLabelText="@string/contact_us_message" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/contact_us_send" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When the user focuses on the EditText it scrolls the view up to accomodate the on screen keyboard. What I want to do is force the automatic scrolling (on select and add new line) to keep the submit button in view at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

So my answer would be to add these lines to your Android Manifest

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding android:isScrollContainer="false" to your scrollview?